# Problem displaying numbers with range slider in inIonic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying yo make a range slider in `Ionic` to set an age between 0 and 25 years old. I want to show the number options when selected, for example:

*I'm 21 years old*

When I slide I want to see the number 21 displayed. (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb2sQ.png) please. Notice: it's in Portuguese)
So far, my code works. But it doesn't display the numbers while I slide the ranger

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range min="o" max="25" color="tertiary">
    <ion-label slot="start">0 ano</ion-label>
    <ion-label slot="end">25 anos</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

I just want to display the number while I slide it so the user can select the correct option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **pin=true**  it will show the number while sliding

```
<ion-item>
<ion-range min="o" max="25" color="tertiary" pin="true">
  <ion-label slot="start">0 ano</ion-label>
  <ion-label slot="end">25 anos</ion-label>
</ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Sorry if it sounded noob, but I'm new to Ionic :) thank you a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to lock and display the number I selected with the pin? So the user will be sure it selected the right number

Comment: Yes there is way check this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-rc0-always-show-ion-range-pin/66724/4